# Can I set hreflangs for two different domains

Tags: seo, hreflang

My client could not get subdomains of his website and he bought a completely different domain but the content and design, everything is the same so those two sites are duplicate site for different locations. Can I set hreflangs for two different domains like this

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://example.com/"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-AR" href="https://ar.differentexample.com/"/>
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, in my experience having unique content in each territory works best but that does not mean that duplicate content targeting different locations does not work, lots of brands do it quite successfully. Secondly, there is nothing wrong with your example.